# c++ cascading with derived class members

Tags: c++, polymorphism

**Note: This is Homework!**

I'm working on a large project at the moment, in which i have 3(that we will focus on) classes, a base class Student, and 2 derived classes Grad and Undergrad, now i'll never explicitly use the student class, but ill be creating a linked list containing both grads and undergrads typecast to student, my question is as to how i may implement cascading with my derived classes i.e.

in my base class i have a small function, wiht the full overwritten implementation in Undergrad

base class:

```
virtual UnderGrad& setMajor(std::string) {}
```

UnderGrad:

```
//purpose: sets the major       
UnderGrad& UnderGrad::setMajor(std::string maj)
{
    major = maj;
    return *this;
}
```

im wondering if this is correct or what the correct implementation of a function so i may use cascading like i.e.

```
curStudent.setStudentNum().setMajor()......
```

is what im doing correct? if so what should my base class return? i.e.

```
return *(new Undergrad(....));
```

**EDIT**
to answer some of the questions 
I simply have to have a linked list that holds 2 classes Grad and UnderGrad both derived form student, in order to sort these lists, amongst other things i need access to the derived classes (unique variables) however i have them cast to Student (as is required by the assignment) so in order to access any class specific data i need some virtual method written to access it (yes in my opinion it seems useless and i could do everything in one class student that i can in these 3 but i cant have 1 class) so would it thus be wrong for me to write virtual methods for use specifically on the derived classes to access variables that would otherwise be 'out of my reach', next the constructor of Undergrad does set the major however if i want to edit any data it seems redundant to get all the old data delete the old node, then create a new node with the old data and a new major

Chris's answers in the comments below where exactly what i needed i think

Comment: If you want that to work for both grads and undergrads, you'll have to return a `Student &`. If it's only applicable for one, do it in that class, not the base class.

Comment: OK that's what i was beginning the think how may i return a reference to the base class, and if im returning a reference to a base class will my derived functions be called or my base

Comment: `return *this;` will do it.

Comment: awsome it'll typecaste i asume ty!

Comment: Going from a derived pointer or reference to a base pointer or reference is a fine implicit conversion.

Comment: perfect yeah im nto greta wiht references yes thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it sounds like your base class is an `Abstract Class`. In other words, you **never** instantiate a class of type `Student`, it is merely an abstraction and a mechanism for code sharing.

In C++ there is no keyword for `abstract` as there is in other OO-languages like `C#, Java`. But you can achieve the abstract mechanism by marking a function as `pure virtual`. In order to do this, simply set a virtual function equal to 0, as in

```
virtual UnderGrad& setMajor(std::string) = 0;
```

Now, you will get a compiler error if any derived classes do not override this function. This provides a contract that says "Anyone who derives student, MUST implement `setMajor`". As such, the `Student` class will not implement this function and won't return anything since the function is `abstract` or `pure virtual`.

As for

```
curStudent.setStudentNum().setMajor()......
```

I don't know what how `setStudentNum` is going to return an object of type student. You might want to break those up into two separate calls. E.g.

```
curStudent.setStudentNum(2058937);
curStudent.setMajor("Computer Science");
```

Comment: Not quite what i was looking for as set major is unique to UnderGrad and i do not want to implement it for Grads (thats why its not pure virtual), and by returning a reference/pointer to the base i can cascade without separate function calls

Comment: @AndrewOtsuki, You'll have to get around the inconsistency that `setMajor` can only be at the start of the chain then, unless you have a default implementation in `Student` that applies for `Graduate`. If `Graduate` shouldn't be able to `setMajor`, it should only appear in `Undergraduate`.

Comment: ah i have a variable holding the degree type with i check, and yep that sounds right, i had implemented cascading when i was allowed 2 different lists, and figured that one out ty

Comment: If setMajor is unique to undergrads, it shouldn't be part of the base class.  The OP should update the question to clarify this, as putting "setMajor" in the base class implies that it is valid to call it on a grad student.

Comment: inst it if i was to define it as pure virtual then it has to be implemented in each, and if i wanted to access derived class specific functions that are not defined in the base class how could that then be accomplised if all i have is a pointer to the base class student

Comment: and im not allowed to do a dynamic cast

Comment: tbh at this point my student class is looking similiar to my undergrad and grad classes combined and im beginning to no longer see a point in having these 2 derived classes(besides the fact i have to)

Comment: You are correct in that, if you have derived classes upcasted to their base class, you will not have access to the derived, non-virtual functions.

To me, this looks like a design or conceptual flaw. You don't want to have the Student class and grad class lugging around an empty `setMajor` function if it is not going to be used. And this will prevent you from calling `setMajor` generically on objects of type `Student`. But why would you want to call `setMajor` for `Student`, if it is not really an aspect of `Student`? Can `setMajor` instead be deferred to the constructor of the `NewGrads`?